# Vagrant provisioning

Tags: mysql, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

Noobie question. I am attempting to write a shell script for my Vagrantfile that loading a database exported, self contained file after the server environment is built. The goal is to build the server, install mariadb, and then load a self contained sql file to populate the database with data.

I added a bootstrap.sh file to the directory with my Vargantfile and in it I added the sequence I do to access the mysql cli. My question is, I know when I put mysql -u username -p, it prompts my next action as the password. Can I put that on the second line to run next or is there something I need to add since its a password prompt.

Something like (bootstrap.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mysql -u username -p
secret-password
```

Any advice or links to better information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the password on the same command line:

```
mysql --user='username' --password='password' ...
```

But I prefer not to put passwords on the command-line. Instead, I create a defaults file containing the credentials. Here's the format of such a file:

```
[client]
user = <username>
password = <password>
```

The mysql client will automatically read options from your global `/etc/my.cnf` file or the current user's `$HOME/.my.cnf`. You can also use a flag to give a specific alternative option file. For example:

```
mysql --defaults-file=/vagrant/my.cnf ...
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

If you want to be even more secure, and you're using MySQL 5.6 or later, you can create an encrypted file containing the credentials. Then use another option to read it:

```
mysql --login-path=/vagrant/mylogin.cnf ...
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html for details on how to create the mylogin.cnf file.